# Find maximum value of $f(x)=2\cos 2x + 4 \sin x$ where $0 < x <\pi$

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

Find the maximum value of $f(x)$ where 
\begin{equation}
 f(x)=2\cos 2x + 4 \sin x \ \
 \text{for} \ \ 0<x<\pi
\end{equation}

Comment: :what are u trying?

Comment: I want to encourage my students (high school) to use math.stackexchange.com to learn and find solution to math problem. This site is not just for higher level education right? Is it okay to populate this site with problems and hopefully get various answers so that they can learn from?

Comment: The simple question I can answer it by my toe, not by my head.

Comment: @Maisam Hedyelloo: Do you reckon? hmmm... not sure about it. I'll give it a try anyway and see what happen. Thanks for your opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x)=2-4\sin^2(x)+4\sin(x)$. Let $t=\sin (x)$. Then $0<t\le 1$. We have a new function:
$$g(t)=-4t^2+4t+2$$.

So $t=\frac12$, we get the maximum of $f(x)$. It is 3.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: writing $\cos2x$ in terms of $\sin x$, you obtain quadratic function.

Comment: I downvote you. You have done nothing for the question.

Comment: sometimes, a little hints like this is enough to open up a solution. thanks

Comment: @Simple We shall assume finding the maximum of quadratic function in a given interval is a simpler problem.

Answer (score 1):

We can utilize algebra to avoid calculus as follows

$$f(x)=2\cos2x+4\sin x$$

$$=2(1-2\sin^2x)+4\sin x$$

$$=2-(4\sin^2x-4\sin x)$$

$$=2-(2\sin x-1)^2+1\le 3$$ as for real $x,(2\sin x-1)^2\ge 0$

the equality occurs if $2\sin x-1=0\iff \sin x=\frac12\implies x=n\pi+(-1)^n\frac\pi6$

For $0<x<\pi, x=\frac\pi6$ or $\pi-\frac\pi6$

Comment: If  the minus vote is due to the absence of calculus, then is the usage of calculus mandatory?

Comment: I downvote you, since I think the simple question become complex in your hand.

Comment: @Simple, not sure where is the complexity. usage of algebra is nice instead of calculus http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264504/finding-range-of-fracx1-x2/264511#264511 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174905/minimum-value-of-given-expression/174930#174930

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=2\cos 2x+4\sin x$

$=2(1-2\sin^2x)+4\sin x$

$=2-4\sin^2x+4\sin x$

$=2-(4\sin^2 x-2(2\sin x)+1)+1$

$=2+1-(2\sin x-1)^2\le (2+1)=3$

Equality holds iff $2\sin x-1=0\Rightarrow \sin x=1/2$

Comment: you missed $4$ (the coefficient of $\sin x$)

Comment: Thanks a lot @labbhattacharjee. I have corrected it.