# What is the supremum and infimum of $n/(1+n^2)$ where $n$ is an element of $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Please help with the proving! I would like to double check my answers.

$\sup = 1/2$

$\max = 1/2$

$\inf = 0$

$\min = \text{No minimum}$

Is this correct? How do I go about showing that no smaller number is also an upper bound?

Comment: What's the domain of $n$? And if you'd like us to double check, please provide your answers.

Comment: n is an element of N

Comment: @Alpha, just to re-confirm, $n$ must be positive integers, right?

Comment: yes n must be positive integers

Answer (score 1):

As $n$ is real, we have $\displaystyle(n-1)^2\ge0\implies n^2+1\ge2n\implies \frac12\ge \frac n{n^2+1}$ the equality occurs if $n=1$

Observe that the value of $\displaystyle \frac n{n^2+1}$ goes arbitrarily close to zero as $n\to\infty$

So, there will be no minimum value of $\displaystyle \frac n{n^2+1}$ for finite $n$

---

Alternatively, let us consider the reciprocal of $\displaystyle \frac n{n^2+1}$ i.e., $\displaystyle \frac{n^2+1}n=n+\frac1n$

As $n>0$ using $A.M.\ge G.M.n+\frac1n\ge 2\sqrt{n\cdot\frac1n}=2$ and it has evidently no maximum value

If the reciprocal has minimum value $(=2)$ only,  what should be the fact of the original function $\displaystyle \frac n{n^2+1}$?

Answer (score 0):

Put $\displaystyle\frac n{1+n^2}=y\iff yn^2-n+y=0$

As $n$ is real, the discriminant of the above quadratic equation in $n$  must be $\ge0$

this will give us the range of $\displaystyle y=\frac n{1+n^2}$

Comment: First, this can only give a superset of the range, not the range itself. Second, one might want to avoid spoonfeeding the OP before they show what they did.

Comment: @Did, if $n$ is real, why will this give a superset, not the exact one? Secondly, this is not a homework

Comment: The argument is that, for $y$ to exist, the discriminant needs to be nonnegative. Do you see why this is only one implication and not an equivalence? // Homework: completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Did, I assumed $n$ to be real due to the tag and the OP has confirmed the nature of $n$ much after the answer was committed.

Comment: Once again, the fact that one assumes the parameter $n$ to be natural or real is irrelevant to the logical flaw in your answer (hence you can stop being fixated on the bizarre idea that it would somehow save the argument).

Comment: @Did, Can you please comment on some of these http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264504/finding-range-of-fracx1-x2,   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472169/find-extreme-values-of-frac2xx4/472193#472193  and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426437/finding-the-range-of-fx-1-x-1x-2

Comment: Sure: all three are wrong for the same reason as here (in 472169 the unrelated argument based on tangent can be made correct if one replaces "we know the range of sin2θ for real θ" by "we know the range of sin2θ for θ in $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$"). Hurkyl even said so in a comment on your accepted answer to 264504 but neither you nor the OP seemed to care.

Comment: @Did, I have utilized  the Article $119-121$ of this(http://archive.org/details/higheralgebraas00kniggoog)

Comment: Glad to know. In the sentence "Therefore y cannot lie between 2 and 6, but may have any other value" on page 90, the first part follows from the reasoning before but the second part does not, unless x can take any real value and one adds a reason. And if one does that, one sees that the argument is NOT that "the discriminant of the above quadratic equation in n must be ≥0" (your post) but that, IF the discriminant is nonnegative, THEN there exists a real x given by the well-known formula such that blablabla. As already said, the confusion between an implication and the reverse one.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem implicitly leads to the question whether zero is or not an element of N. About this question there is not general agreement among the mathematicians of the world. If yes, then there is a minimun (which is contrary to your result)