# Range of function with limit?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a function

$$f(x)=\frac{2x^2 - x - 1}{x^2 + 3x + 2}$$

from the interval  $[0,\infty)$

The limit of this function is $2$. Is the range then simply from $f(0)$ to $2$, and if yes, would I write it as $[f(0],2]$ or $[f(0),2)$, i.e open brackets or closed?

Also, would i first need to argue that it's a monotonous - growing - function, thus $f(0)$ has to be the lower end of the range? THX

Comment: Because it never reaches $2$ you can't have a closed bracket.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264504/finding-range-of-fracx1-x2?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to prove your function is increasing. No too difficult, since the derivative is, after simplification,

$$f'(x)=\frac{7x^2+10x+1}{(x^2+3x+2)^2}>0$$

Hence the range is $[f(0), \lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)[=[-1/2,2[$, *open* on the right.

---

I'm not sure what you mean in your comment, anyway here is a plot of $f(x)$ (blue) and $f'(x)$ (red). When the curve of $f$ is flattening, the derivative tends to zero, which is rather expected.

[image]

Comment: Can I ask something? I plotted the two in the same coordinate system, with domain [0,infinity[ and I noticed that the derivative is always positive but decreases in areas where f(x) is actually getting steeper. Shouldn't f'(x) go up when slope of f(x) is getting steeper? Or is there just somethin wrong with my plot?

Comment: @Dan See plot above.

Answer (score 0):

You need the open bracket at $2$. And since $f(0) = -\frac 12$, the range of $f$ is given by $$\left[-\frac{1}{2}, 2\right)$$

Yes, since $f$ is monotonically increasing, $f(0) = -\frac 12$ is its greatest lower bound. So all you need here is to prove (establish) that it is monotonically increasing. Furthermore, the limit as $x\to +\infty f(x) = 2$, although $f(x) \neq 2$ for any $x$, hence the half-open interval.

Comment: All right, thanks, I figured that. One more thing; if I were to "prove" this limit, I would then need to find an integer N, such that for any epsilon, |f(n) - 2)| < epsilon for any n > N... how would I go about finding such an N, for example for epsilon = 1? I tried the usual method of writing down |f(n) - 2)| < 1, and then trying to manipulate, but it seemed too complex.

Comment: Note that the limit as $x \to + \infty = 2$.

Comment: @Johhny: The asymptotic behavior at $\pm\infty$ of the ratio of any two polynomials is the same as the behavior of the ratio of the leading terms of the polynomials.

Comment: Alternately, if you simplify $f(x)-2$, you get 
$$-\frac{7x+5}{x^2+3x+2}$$
And clearly this has limit $0$ when $x\rightarrow+\infty$.

Comment: I still don't quiiite get how I am supposed to isolate x (or "N") from that in terms of epsilon....

Comment: @Dain $\forall\epsilon>0$ (and $\epsilon<1$, to simplify), there is $A=12/\epsilon$ such that $\forall x\geq A$,
$$|f(x)-2|=\frac{7x+5}{x^2+3x+2}\leq\frac{7/x+5/x^2}{1+3/x+2/x^2}\leq 7/x+5/x^2\leq 12/x \leq \epsilon$$
The last steps hold because $x\geq12/\epsilon>1$ so that $x^2>x$, and $x>A$ implies that $1/x<1/A=\epsilon/12$.

Answer (score 0):

If you can prove that your function is monotonous, then you need to write this argument first, and then you can deduce that the range is $[f(0),2[$.