# Can I pick any N in the epsilon N - definition?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If I were asked to pick a $N$ that would satisfy the definition such that for any $n > N$, the distance between $f(n)$ and the limit would be smaller than a specific epsilon....

...can I just pick $N$'s at random that would satisfy this, and then say that for any $n > N$ it would be true as well?

I think no; just because it works for a given $N$, doesn't mean it'll work for *any* $n > N$... but then somebody told me that it would work, because, and he said it like this, "once it's close to the limit, it stays close, and only gets closer", so if the distance between $f(N)$ and the limit is smaller than a given epsilon, then that would remain true for any $n>N$.

Is this true? Is he making some assumptions that aren't always given? Or is it complete bollocks?

Comment: I think you misunderstood that the definition of the limit (which is not that easy to understand when you see it first). Could you give us an specific example?

Comment: For functions that approach the limit "nicely" it is often true. In general it is not. So if you have found an $N$ such that $f(N)$ is "close enough" you must always verify that the same is true for all larger $n$.

Comment: If $|f(N)-L|<\epsilon$ for some $N$, it's absolutely not guaranteed in general that it's still true for all $n>N$. If the sequence $f(n)$ is converging, it means this will happen eventually (you will find some $N$ such that all $n>N$ satisfies the inequality), but actually it's the definition of convergence.

Comment: Hi guys. Sorry, I forgot to mention something that might be of importance; f(n) is MONOTONOUSLY INCREASING.... but if this is true, and it is bounded by the limit L, then it HAS to be true that if N works, then it WILL work for all n>N, right? Because for bigger and bigger n's, it approaches its limit (i.e. gets closer), as it's bounded by its limit but always increasing for bigger n's? Am I correct in saying this?

Comment: Yeah. If it increases monotonically then this is justifiable

Comment: $N$ is likely to be related to $\epsilon$ in some way, and you want the statement to be true for all positive $\epsilon$, so picking $N$s at random are unlikely to satisfy this.

Comment: @Dain If this question is related to [your comment here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/928826/range-of-function-with-limit/928831#comment1917428_928831), then see my answer below that comment. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[In the general case]

Suppose you somehow found some $N$ such that for any $n > N$, we have $|f(n)-L| < \epsilon$.

Then any $N' \ge N$ will also "work," that is, for any $n > N'$, we have $|f(n)-L| < \epsilon$.

However, as Jean-Claude pointed out it is **not** true that $|f(n)-L|<\epsilon$ implies that for all $n' \ge n$ we have $|f(n')-L| < \epsilon$. But, as I am writing this, you have mentioned that $f$ is monotonic, so in that case, this does hold.