# If 'x' is real and $\frac{x^2-x+c}{x^2+x+2c}$ can take all real values find the interval in which $c$ lies

Tags: roots, quadratics

> If 'x' is real and  $\frac{x^2-x+c}{x^2+x+2c}$ can take all real values find the interval in which $c$ lies.

**My approach:**
$y=\frac{x^2-x+c}{x^2+x+2c}$

$\forall x, y$ is real only if ${x^2+x+2c}\neq0$
Hence the equation ${x^2+x+2c}$ has no root.
$D<0$
$b^2-4ac<0$
$1-8c<0$
$c>1/8$

But the answer is $(-6,0)$.

I can't figure out why.

Comment: Try like http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264504/finding-range-of-fracx1-x2?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @user35508 Why will the numerator matter, on putting any value of x in the numerator the numerator will always be real. The denominator will also be real for all real values of x. The only time when x is not real is when the denominator is zero.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee but why is this wrong?

Comment: Oh I get it... I wasn't comprehending the question right, I thought no value of y should be complex but the question wants y to have **all** real values. Hence the function should be onto.

Comment: The problem never said the value is defined everywhere.  If the denominator has a root then y is not defined and .... so what?  That's not disallowed.

Comment: My phone doesn't update. Sigh. It really bugs me. I deleted my comment because user 35508 was trying to say if c=2 then y is greater than or equal to 0 and cam't take on all reals.  And s/he was right.  I was wrong.